# merging duplicate values and copying between tables

Tags: perl

This is how my situation looks like. I have two tables:

```
Table 1

C0   C1   C2   C3    ...    C8
     1                      10
     2                      50
     3                      70
     3                      20

Table 2

C0   C1   C2   C3    ...    C7
     1                      
     2                      
     3                      

Table 2 should become like this

C0   C1   C2   C3    ...    C7
     1                      x = 10
     2                      x = 50
     3                      x = 70,20
```

So basicly what I want to do is compare the values of C1 of both tables. If the values are the same then the values of C8 (table 1) should be copied to C7 (table 2) and "x =" should be added. However when there is a duplicate value in C1 (table1), like here the 3, then in table 2 these values should be put next to each other, seperated by a ',' (like here x = 70,20)

This is what I have so far

```
my $table1 = $ARGV[0];
my $table2 = $ARGV[1];

# Open my file (I use exactly the same code for opening table 2)
unless ($table1) {
    print "Enter filename of file:\n";
    $table1 = <STDIN>;
    chomp $table1;
    }
open(DATA1,'<',$table1) or die "Could not open file $filename $!";

# Here I push the values of C8 in table 1 to the same row
my %info = ()    
while (<DATA1>) {
    my @columns = split;
if( exists $info{ $columns[1] } ) {
    push @{ $info{ $columns[1] }->{var} }, $columns[8];
}
else {
    $info{ $columns[1] } = { var =>[ $columns[8] ] }
}
}
```

If this is all correct, the only thing I need to do now is to copy the values to C7 (table 2) and let them start with "x="

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Of all languages, surely PERL has some CSV module that could help with this?

Comment: Sugeestions: Please use `use strict; use warinings;`. Also, avoid bareword Filehandles(DATA1). Use scalar variables as filehandles.

Comment: Can you explain the structure of `$info`?

Comment: I forgot to specify %info. Changed it now

Comment: You can delete the `else` part. Perl has **autovivification**.

Comment: what file format does "Table 1" and "Table 2" actually use?  Are they tab seperated values with a header?  Also your example makes the problem definition clear but some real data - a few lines of it - from "Table 1" and "Table 2" would make it clear how to read the input and also what the desired output is like

Comment: @Vorsprung Table 1 and Table 2 are tab-seperated text files. They both contain a header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking for.  See `perldoc perldsc`  and `perldoc perllol` for details on how the access to the @line in %t1 works

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $table1 = $ARGV[0];
my $table2 = $ARGV[1];

open(my $fh1,$table1) || die "$! $table1";
open(my $fh2,$table2) || die "$! $table1";

#discard the first lines which are the headers
my $headers1=<$fh1>;
my $headers2=<$fh2>;

#set up data from table1
my %t1=();
while(<$fh1>) {
    chomp;  #remove newlines
    my @line=split(/\t/);  #split on tabs
    my $keyfield=$line[1]; #key is C1
    push @{$t1{$keyfield}}, $line[8];
}

#read from table2 and write output
while(<$fh2>) {
    chomp; #remove newlines
    my @line=split(/\t/);  #split on tabs
    my $keyfield=$line[1]; #key is C1
    my @x=();
    if (exists($t1{$keyfield}) ) {
        push @x,@{$t1{$keyfield}}; # get the C8 values from t1
    }
    for my $c (0..6) {
        print $line[$c],"\t"; #print C0 to C6 with a tab seperator
    }
    print "x = ",join(",",@x),"\n";    #do x=70,20 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. It already helped me a lot. It however not exactly doing what I want. When the lines are unique, it prints out this "x = .,10" for line 1 in the example. It should print "x = 10". I don't know where this "." comes from ...

Comment: I guess that you are reading a dot as data from table2,  position C7 in table2.  This sets $x[0] to '.' and the join prints it.  If you are not using the data in C7 of table2 then alter the @x to be an empty list like this ``my @x=$line[7];        #C7 from t2`` becomes ``my @x=();``  Hope this helps.  Accepting this answer would be nice...

Comment: Thanks this solved this issue. There is still something else: the joining doesn't appear to work. For the line 3 in my example, I get as output x = 20 instead of x = 70,20. So it looks as if he forgets the first duplicate line

Comment: another edit, taking into account what you just said.  It now makes a list of the C8 values in t1 and outputs that when there is a match of C1 in t1 and t2 - I hope we've finally got there ??? :)

Comment: Thanks, it works indeed. You've learned me a lot about Perl! Still two things: my table 2 contains in fact more than 8 columns. In the script you print the first 7 columns with `for my $c (0..6)` and than the 8th column with the `x = ` values. However there are still 4 extra columns that should be printed after the 8th column. Can I define that in the `for my c$ ` statement? And then the last thing: how can I save this table now to a .txt file?

Comment: alter the ``(0..6)`` to ``(0..12)`` and make it so that ``if ($c==8) { `` do the print with the join in it else just print $line[$c].  To save to a file see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html

Comment: To save to a file I added `open(my $c,'>',"changed.txt") || die "Can't write new file: $!";` after the other two `open` statements. After the `while(<$fh2>)` loop, I added `close ($c);` I get an outputfile called changed.txt, but it's empty. I'm doing something wrong ...

Comment: you need to alter the print statements to use $fh2, or ``select $fh2`` as the default.  See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#print

Comment: Can you clarify that in the script? Cause I don't see how I can change the print statements to use $fh2 ...

Comment: It is in the perldocs, it really is!  ``print $fh2 $line[$c],"\t";`` is an example

Comment: I'm really not seeing it ... I found somewhere that I should put an `open` statement at the beginning like in one of my previous comments. Is that correct? But then I should specify a new variable no? And if I add `$fh2` after `print` like in your previous comment, it's not working

Comment: sorry, not ``$fh2``, ``$c``, my mistake

Comment: Thanks, the printing works now. However still two things which are not how they should be: 1) the columns should be seperated with a tab, which is OK, but there should be no tab after the last column, only a newline. How should I do that? 2) I want to overwrite the values from the column in which I put the "x = " data, now I'm just pasting the "x = " before the data that were already there.

Comment: Could you please help me with the previous questions?

Comment: why not start another stackoverflow question thread?  I'm sure someone else can pick up this.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to map an array reference into a string!

What you can do is,

1. Copy the array's data in a `$string`.
2. Concatenate `$string` as `$string = "x = $string";`.
3. Assign this modified `$string` to the hash(`%info`) in place of `array reference`. Sice both are scalars, assignment shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Could you please specify in my script how & where I should do that?